Create an Existing Type Entity in the Database and Add it to a Data Entity Without Ever Loading the Type Entity Symfony or Builder with no params
I am facing a rather specific problem. We’ve inherited an application that has been around for a long time, doesn’t have any test suite, and is hard to maintain. To improve this, we’ve created a builder that should help us create a data entity, and this entity can be of type A, B, or C. I would like to create a new entity and assign it a new TypeA which contains the type’s ID, but without having to load it directly from the database, as that would mean passing a repository into the controller method, then into Method A, which calls Method 2, and Method 3... and this happens everywhere in the application. From a workload perspective, this is just not feasible.
I need something like this :
<?php

class TypeA extends Type {

    private ?int $id = 1;

}

class Data {

    private Type $type;
    
    public function setType() {
        #code
    }

}

$data = DataBuilder::build();
$data->setType(new TypeA());
$em->persist($data);
$em->flush();

Thanks in advance !
Or if anyone has a solution where I don't need to pass any parameters into my builder, I would be very interested as well !

What are the versions of PHP and Symfony you are working on? Different versions may need different solutions (e.g. if PHP >= 8.1 you can simply use enums)

Thanks for your response, how can i do that ? At my last try, an error appear telling me entity is not persisted

If you are using PHP >= 8.1 (which you should since 8.0 & below is already EOL), you can use enum, as follows:
enum Type: int {
    case A = 1;
    case B = 2;
    case C = 3;
}

#[ORM\Entity]
class Data {

    #[ORM\Column(enumType: Type::class)]
    private Type $type;
    
    public function setType(Type $type) {
        $this->type = $type;
    }
}

$data = DataBuilder::build();
$data->setType(Type::A);
$em->persist($data);
$em->flush();

But if you are using PHP < 8.1, you can use the class constants trick, as follows:
#[ORM\Entity]
class Data {
    const TYPE_A = 1;
    const TYPE_B = 2;
    const TYPE_C = 3;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private int $type;
    
    public function setType(int $type) {
        $this->type = $type;
    }
}

$data = DataBuilder::build();
$data->setType(Data::TYPE_A);
$em->persist($data);
$em->flush();

